# How to install/setup XMLStarlet in Linux?

Tags: linux, xmlstarlet

I'm fairly new to Linux and shell scripting; and have a requirement to parse and query an xml. I was able to find and use XML starlet for Windows successfully.

However, my goal is to have that run on Linux via a shell script.

Can anyone please share the steps to install and configure **XMLStarlet** on Linux?

Thanks!

Comment: What flavor of Linux and what have you tried? [Ubuntu?](http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/vivid/universe/x/xmlstarlet/install/index.html)

Comment: `apt-get install xmlstarlet `?

Answer (score 16):

For Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xmlstarlet
```

For CentOS:
It is present in epel repo, download the repo and enable it

```
sudo yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

Confirm if it is enabled or not

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
grep -re enabled=1
```

This should show

```
epel.repo:enabled=1
```

Then Download xmlstarlet

```
sudo yum -y install xmlstarlet
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Ubuntu/Debian run the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xmlstarlet
```

if the OS is Centos

```
 Download latest epel-release rpm  http://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/

 Install epel-release rpm:
 $ sudo rpm -Uvh epel-release*rpm

 Install xmlstarlet rpm package:
 $ sudo yum install xmlstarlet
```

or download from https://centos.pkgs.org/6/epel-x86_64/xmlstarlet-1.3.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm.html